# disable a color from color dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, colordialog

i want to allow users to pick a background color for my program using a `ColorDialog` but as my label's text is black in color, I want to make the user not able to pick black from the color dialog so that the color will not overlap my label text color. is there any way I can do that? I have also thought of bringing up an error message if the user selects black as shown below but after the color dialog comes up again the color I selected does not becomes the BackColor of my form

```
if (color.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if(color.Color == Color.Black)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Color cannot be black", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        color.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        BackColor = color.Color;
        backColor = color.Color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `while` until proper `Color` is selected.

Comment: Have you considered switching to a light label text color when a dark background color is selected, rather than just telling the users that their choices are wrong?

Comment: Let the user choose both `BackColor` and `ForeColor` for the form. This way they can choose what combination of color they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use while instead of if when checking for color:

```
if (color.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    while(color.Color == Color.Black)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Color cannot be black", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        color.ShowDialog();
    }
    BackColor = color.Color;
    backColor = color.Color;
}
```

This way, unless you pick a color that's not black, it will show an error message and open the ColorDialog again.
As to why the color wouldn't change for you after you reopened the dialog, it is because you are changing the background color only in the else clause, therefore if you at first chose black the BackColor wouldn't change.
Another way to solve your problem is by changing the color of your labels to white if the chosen color is black(don't forget to change the label text back to black when another color is chosen).

Comment: thank you guys. The while loop worked for me. I cant change the label color cause i have alot of forms and would talk alot of time

Comment: @LimJunWei `ForeColor` and `BackColor` are ambient properties and if you change them in the base form, they will change for all controls.

Comment: You should probably check for the user pressing the Cancel button on the second ShowDialog call.